# Fire ajax event every 10 seconds after page is loaded

Tags: ajax, jsf

Is it possible to fire an ajax event with JSF after page is loaded, for example on every 10 seconds?

I mean:

```
<f:ajax listener="#{bean.mymethod()}" />
```

I would like to invoke this method every 10 seconds passed after page is loaded. I don't want to reload the entire page by JavaScript refresh.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This process is called "polling".

This feature is not provided by the standard JSF `<f:ajax>`. You'd need to look for a 3rd party JSF component library. Based on your [question history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/894913/cichy?tab=questions), you're using PrimeFaces, or at least already familiar with it. In that case, you can just use its `<p:poll>` component for the job. See also [the PrimeFaces `<p:poll>` showcase page](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/poll.xhtml) whose code is extracted below:

View:

```
<h:form id="form">  
    <h:outputText id="txt_count" value="#{counterBean.count}" />  

    <p:poll interval="3"   
            listener="#{counterBean.increment}" update="txt_count" />  
</h:form>
```

Bean:

```
public class CounterBean implements Serializable{  

    private int count;  

    public int getCount() {  
        return count;  
    }  

    public void setCount(int count) {  
        this.count = count;  
    }  

    public void increment() {  
        count++;  
    }  
}
```

In your particular case you thus need something like:

```
<p:poll interval="10" listener="#{bean.mymethod}" />
```

Comment: Thank you, I read all od your answers in stackoverflow and I must admit I was counting on you ... :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<a4j:poll action="#{bean.mymethod()}" interval="10000"/>
```

Comment: How did you know that OP is using RichFaces? I'm not reading that anywhere in the current question, nor in all previous questions. There are only hints that OP is using PrimeFaces.